# Задача на сортировку и подсчет уникальных слов в списке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

на обучающем курсе задана следующая задача:
Дан текст на языке племени Мумба-Юмба. Выведите все слова, встречающиеся в тексте, разделяя их пробелом. Слова должны быть отсортированы по убыванию их количества появления в тексте, а при одинаковой частоте появления — в алфавитном порядке.

Подсказка. После того, как вы создадите словарь всех слов, вам захочется отсортировать его по частоте встречаемости слова. Желаемого можно добиться, если создать список, элементами которого будут кортежи из двух элементов: частота встречаемости слова и само слово. Например, [(2, 'hi'), (1, 'what'), (3, 'is')]. Тогда стандартная сортировка будет сортировать список кортежей, при этом кортежи сравниваются по первому элементу, а если они равны — то по второму. Это почти то, что требуется в задаче, а чтобы сделать то что нужно — вспомните про параметр key в сортировке.

В этой задачи нужно сдать только ответ для входного файла. Ссылка на входной файл

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Wvn0nT8MVll6Oj1KvRDWq3Z7ekV4xLg2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113335581115004287089&rtpof=true&sd=true

Написала код для этой задачи. Вроде все корректно, все работает. Но тестирующая система не принимает ответ.
Прошу подсказать, что ей не нравится в моих выходных данных. Может быть, не надо в конце знак перевода строки заменять пробелом? Всю башку уже сломала.
Вот код:

```
fin = open('test1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
words = fin.read().replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')
words_count = dict()
words_count = dict.fromkeys(set(words), 0)
for w in words:
    words_count[w] += 1
words_sorted = sorted(words_count.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
for p in words_sorted:
    print(p[0], end=" ")
fin.close()
```

Comment: файл по ссылке доступен только зарегистрированных пользователей. Либо разместите его в открытом доступе, либо приведите в своем вопросе небольшой фрагмент данных.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Исправила. В тексте вопроса разместила новую ссылку на расшаренный файл с моего Google диска.